# Program to automate software usage

Tags: python, automation

I want to write a program that can:

Open an application. (I successfully executed the application using the `subprocess` module)

Use the application. (How do I automate a task on that particular software? Is it possible? For example, the software would require me login and python and automatically login with my credentials and proceed to automate my typical usage like opening projects)

Close the application.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir("../../Desktop/Sublime/Sublime Text 2") #Directory need to adjust to find teamviewer

print "Starting python..."

switch = True
activator1 = True
activator2 = True

startBoolean = True
exitBoolean = True
container = None

def startTimer(startTime , exitTime):
    global dateTime
    global startBoolean
    global exitBoolean
    dateTime = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')
    print "Current Time: " +dateTime+ "| Start Time: " +startTime +"| Exit Time: "+exitTime
    if dateTime >= startTime:
        startBoolean = False
        print "start boolean: "+ str(startBoolean)
    if dateTime >= exitTime:
        exitBoolean = False
        print  "exit boolean: "+ str(exitBoolean)
    return [startBoolean,exitBoolean]

def startApplication(startTime):
    if dateTime >= startTime:
        print "Launching Application..."
        process = subprocess.Popen(["./sublime_text"],shell=True) #This is using ubuntu terminal command. Might need to change the command to fits other OS.

def stopApplication(exitTime):
    if dateTime >= exitTime:
        print "Exiting Application..."
        process = subprocess.Popen(["killall sublime_text"],shell=True)

startTime = raw_input("Project Launch Time: ")
exitTime = raw_input("Project Exit time: ")

while switch:
    startTimer(startTime , exitTime)
    global container
    container = startTimer(startTime , exitTime)
    if container!=None:
        if activator1==True:
            if container[0] == False:
                print "clear1"
                activator1 = False #Cannot activate < 1.
                startApplication(startTime)
        if activator2==True:
            if container[1] == False:
                print "clear2"
                activator2 = False #Cannot activate < 1.
                stopApplication(exitTime)
```

Comment: If you are on Windows, you may want to look into AutoHotKey (http://www.autohotkey.com/) instead of Python for automating software usage. Be careful storing your credentials in a file that someone might be able to read.

Comment: HI all. I have just posted the entirety of my codes. I'm just sublime as an example.

Comment: @geoffreykoh Can I know what output your experting !!

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use [pyAutoIt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt/0.3)

I am giving sample code for Notepad to save it in required location and required path.

```
import autoit,time
autoit.run("notepad.exe")
autoit.win_wait_active("Untitled - Notepad")
time.sleep(5)
autoit.control_send("Untitled - Notepad", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
autoit.control_send("Untitled - Notepad", "Edit1", "test-2")
#time.sleep(5)
autoit.win_close("Untitled - Notepad")
autoit.control_click("Notepad", "Button1")
#time.sleep(5)
autoit.win_wait_active("Save As")
#time.sleep(5)
autoit.control_send("Save As", "Edit1","Path-to-save")
autoit.control_send("Save As", "Edit1", "file-name")
autoit.control_click("Save As", "Button1")
```

Answer (score 0):

[pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) is also great GUI automation solution on Python.

Example:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe")

app.untitled_SublimeText2.Wait('ready', timeout=10) # just for possible slow start
app.untitled_SublimeText2.MenuSelect('File->Open file')
app.Open.FilenameEdit.SetText('path to the project')
app.Open.Open.Click()
app.Open.WaitNot('visible') # just to make sure it's closed

main_window = app["project_name - Sublime Text 2"]

# print access names for all available controls on the main window
main_window.PrintControlIdentifiers()
```

There is also GUI helper [SWAPY](https://github.com/pywinauto/SWAPY), pywinauto object inspector and code generator.